# inputMismatchException java

Tags: java, inputmismatchexception

*( ANSWER: in the switch case I forgot my break statements and I guess that was throwing the Scanner off! )*

I'm writing a program to read a file that contains three kinds of shapes, followed by their corresponding dimension and write them into an object array. Circles list their radius, Squares their edgelength, but for Triangles their base and height! I wrote what was is logical to me, but my code throws InputMismatchException errors and I'm having trouble finding where I'm going wrong.

The file that the scanner reads is straightforward, A string, followed by 1 or (if the string is a triangle) 2 doubles. I figured I'd create a variable for the triangle's height, and under the condition that the string is a Triangle, it should read another double into that variable. But it throws a mismatchException?

```
for (int i = 0; fs.hasNext(); i++) {
  String word = fs.next();
  double field = fs.nextDouble();
  double triangleH = 0.0;
  switch (word) {
  case circle:
    shape[i] = new Circle(field);
  case square:
    shape[i] = new Square(field);
  case triangle:
    triangleH = fs.nextDouble();
    //^^^line where the error is thrown 
    shape[i] = new IsoscelesTriangle(field, triangleH);
  }
}
```

this is a sample of the file 'fs' is reading.

```
triangle 385.64 796.55
circle 455.71
triangle 697.73 261.17
circle 273.11
triangle 1051.95 879.48
triangle 425.96 772.16
square 864.19
```

the IsoscelesTriangle class looks like this

```
public class IsoscelesTriangle implements Shape {
  private double base = 0.0;
  private double height = 0.0;
  private double area = 0.0;

  public IsoscelesTriangle(double b, double h) {
    setBase(b);
    setHeight(h);
    setArea(b, h);
  }
  //more methods
}
```

Comment: show us the isosceles triangle method does it accept double, double?

Comment: public IsoscelesTriangle(double b, double h) {
    setBase(b);
    setHeight(h);
    setArea(b, h);
  }

Comment: @JasonVanBenschoten Thats a class. Does that class has the constructor?

Comment: oh right, @EvanJones please update the question, dont put it in comments.

Comment: got it, I updated the question

Comment: I forgot my break statements in the switch case *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error in your code, may be in your file on a part that was not posted here there is not a float value next to the triangle

```
double nextDouble()
```

Returns the next token as a long. If the next token is not a float or is out of range, InputMismatchException is thrown.

Please cry catching the Exception print it to see more insights.

Comment: I just realized i'm an idiot, I didn't put any break statements in. Now the errors are gone!!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the input file. I removed dots and used commas and everything run fine. Try this input:

```
triangle 385,64 796,55
circle 455,71
triangle 697,73 261,17
circle 273,11
triangle 1051,95 879,48
triangle 425,96 772,16
square 864,19
```